# How to mount root.disk from WUBI when booted from dual boot install of Ubuntu?

Tags: wubi, mount, ntfs, ext4

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTFS.  On the same disk, I have another Win7.  On the NTFS Win7, I have buntu 11.04 running on a ext4 partition that was installed with Wubi.
I'd like to be able to access my buntu 11.04 files, from my Ubuntu 12.04 OS. Is this possible?

I was thinking this might work:

> mount -t ext4  -r /dev/sda4/ubuntu/disks/root.disk  /media/wubi

Or maybe mount a mount:

> mount -t ntfs  -r /dev/sda4  /media/win7Wubi
>   mount -t ext4  -r /media/win7Wubi/ubuntu/disks/root.disk  /media/buntu1104

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly *mount a mount*, but close. You are supposed to mount a block device contained on a file inside a filesystem that, obviously, is inside a real block device.

In other words: How much wood would a woodchuck chuck if a woodchuck could chuck wood?

The key is the parameter `-o loop`.

Assuming that:

- The Windows partition is `/dev/sda4`.
- The root partition file is located on `/ubuntu/disks/root.disk` inside the Windows partition.
- The directories `/media/win7Wubi` and `/media/ubuntu1104` were already created.

Use these two commands on this order:

```
mount -t ntfs /dev/sda4 /media/win7Wubi
mount -t ext4 -o loop /media/win7Wubi/ubuntu/disks/root.disk /media/ubuntu1104
```

Comment: I'd like to add the ext4 to fstab so it is there @ startup.     uuid=some#here /media/win7Wubi/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ext4 ro 0 0  Is not working for me.  Flag missing?

Comment: I'm not sure what I saw earlier, bu there is no UUID for this 'loop' partition.  Is there a way to auto-mount a loop partition?

Comment: Yep, instead of using the `UUID=xxx` identifier, just write the device name, on this case the filename: `/media/win7Wubi/ubuntu/disks/root.disk /media/win7Wubi/ubuntu/disks/root.disk ext4 loop,rw 0 0`. Don't forget the `loop` option, and change that `ro` to `rw` or you won't be able to write on there. Please take a look at `man fstab` and `man mount` for details.

Comment: I think you mean this: '/media/win7Wubi/ubuntu/disks/root.disk /media/ubuntu1104 ext4 loop,rw 0 0'  It worked.  I tried the 'man', there was no mention of 'loop'.  Can I name it inside fstab?  Natilus is giving it a generic name.  Thanks

Comment: Set label with: e2label /media/win7Wubi/ubuntu/disks/root.disk oldUbuntu