# Setting up boot/efi in fstab

Tags: boot, dual-boot, mount, uefi, fstab

I'll try to be brief on the backstory.

I recently bought a really cheap slim notebook,came with a low power celeron, 4gb ram and a 32gb eMMC drive, it also features a 500GB internal Sata HDD I added myself.

The thing had an impressively locked down bios which would only run windows10.
I managed to run a win10 installer, wipe down the eMMC drive and install windows10 on a 200GB partition I made in the hdd. In order to install Ubuntu, my last resource was WUBI-UEFI fork. I made a ntfs-logical partition in the eMMC drive and let the older 16.04 WubiUefi installer do its magic (the 18.04 one wouldn't work) and I was finally able to have Ubuntu running! yay!

But now I want to do-release-upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04LTS, I don't want 16.04! And believe me, I cannot install from USB, or with wubi using 18.04, I simply cannot. My only wish is to do this upgrade now and use the system for school, which stats next tuesday for me.

The problem is:

> EFI System Partition (ESP) not usable
>
> Your EFI System Partition (ESP) is not mounted at /boot/efi. Please
>   ensure that it is properly configured and try again.

The partition ubuntu is in, is actually a ntfs partition (I know, that's silly, but there was no other way) The emmc drive is called /dev/mmcblk1p1 and has /root as mounting point, which makes the whole thing work.
According to Gparted there is is a 100mb EFI System Partition in /dev called /sda2, so I guess /dev/sda2 is either what I need, or just part of the windows install I shouldn't mess with? (help here).

I want the ESP mounted, so I can upgrade to 18.04 and have a somewhat normal and stable system that will work until christmas, without having to fiddle with anything. And I believe I also want fstab to mount it every time the PC is turned on.

I found this post on this forum: 
[How to mount root.disk from WUBI when booted from dual boot install of Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/243621/how-to-mount-root-disk-from-wubi-when-booted-from-dual-boot-install-of-ubuntu)
It's old but I think it has the exact answer! However I can't fully understand it, and maybe I just need someone to break it down for me, on a dumber way lol.

This is my current fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/host/ubuntu/disks/root.disk /               ext4    loop,errors=remount-ro 0       1
/host/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk none            swap    loop,sw         0       0
```

What can I add to fstab to make this work? Please I can't mess the fstab as there is no way for me to plug in a linux usb drive, enter the terminal there and delete the line if I can't boot :(
Sadly, I need to keep that win10 partition for a few school tasks that may came every couple of weeks, although I'll be using Ubuntu like 95% of the time.

Ty for any possible answers!